# Return value of get_background_color

Tags: theme-customizer, custom-background

I want to return the value of `get_background_color` but that value isn't showing up.

```
<?php echo get_background_color(); ?>
```

I have `colors` enabled in my customizer, and there is the option 'background color', so I'm kinda confused about this option.

---

And also, how can I add a colorpicker option in the customizer so I can remove the `colors` section? I have tried:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('bgcolor');
$wp_customize->add_control('bgcolor', array(
    'label'   => 'Background color',
    'section' => 'themeoptions',
    'type'    => 'color-picker',
));
```

and

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('bgcolor');
$wp_customize->add_control('bgcolor', array(
    'label'   => 'Background color',
    'section' => 'themeoptions',
    'type'    => 'color',
));
```

but with the above example the customizer goes blank.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add custom background support in your theme you need to register the default [custom background](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) support.

Example:-

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function(){
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array( 
        'default-color' => 'black' //Default color 
    )); 
});
```

Now you will see a new section *Background Image* in customizer and in *Color* you will see a new option *Background color*

Once you will save the settings you can use `echo get_background_color();`